# javascript dynamic filters with OR results

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with multiple fields, i.e.

```
Person
{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    addressLines: string[];
}[];
```

I also have dynamic search parameters, i.e.

```
parameters: ['mary', 'oregon'] //may be a longer/shorter array
```

Assuming my input is:

```
[
    { name: 'john mark', age: '29', addressLines: ['566 long street', 'oregon']},
    { name: 'williams', age: '30', addressLines: ['oregon']},
    { name: 'moore mary', age: '40', addressLines: ['street 61', 'salt lake']}
]
```

My output should be:

```
[
    { name: 'john mark', age: '29', addressLines: ['566 long street', 'oregon']}, // oregon
    { name: 'moore mary', age: '40', addressLines: ['street 61', 'salt lake']} //mary
]
```

How can I implement this using the filter method? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
type Persons =
{
    name: string;
    age: number;
    addressLines: string[];
}[];

const personArray: Persons = [
    { name: 'john mark', age: 29, addressLines: ['566 long street', 'oregon']},
    { name: 'williams', age: 30, addressLines: ['oregon']},
    { name: 'moore mary', age: 40, addressLines: ['street 61', 'salt lake']}
]

const parameters = ['mary', 'oregon']


const foundPersons = personArray.filter((person) => {
    let matched = false
    parameters.forEach((param) => {
        // Check if name matches
        if (person.name.includes(param)) matched = true;
        // Check if address matches
        person.addressLines.forEach((addressPart) => {
            if (addressPart.includes(param)) matched = true;
        })
        // Check if age matches
        if (person.age == param) matched = true;
    })
    return matched
})
```

See it in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gO0VAvAKAN7akKlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbgKJKauIFcyAjBGyJQSAEzHwIiRABlG06rQbMA2gF0WUbAF8NW7NgDGaWlEhI0AQXjwSIanEvosUVe0K5i5bgHIAVsgAFqhQZCTwANa+ADSiXNQATACcceKS0nIKiNSqvgCsAGyFUAA2aEw0dBAQwLFQvshSTGi+6joxHlBepBTUvgDu9KWl9OSI9ZzcAMwADGkSUjLyqIpujc2t7Z0iPT79ZMhN0OHwIJMJUAAs86KLmStreco1wFCFAIz1vogkpW+lEiRCBtHTYdSGEzoN5gCI+YAIDCYdanc5xDYQFqoNqGYymN4AM2QPFQYicKBcyIsFJsdhAADoCcMEfAABSs6loACUWAAfN0uqVamESMAjEEIGJXAS-ogIF1YXYKCzEIymgBREji9mK8g8zD8-AiEQAehNUAAwhKjJEoPQCd4KCKxRLEF0RPaoBzEWh6b0IPTGEZSjwxNIOXCyFyeeEXZLXHQeBBhMbCGbLdbbZ70ksMLHxdJ3UROah6TmHtk1fBNdrWeWZDAIsB9Yai6nPXX7g2m4HUMHQ+HdVGY6KC1LkYnk22oDoudP01aIDa7Q6ps6C27U4QOyWy1wsFTIyO4+OoJOU4RZ10pMAePBQvmJWJdHO8ehkEL6eUmKyiSSyT66BckAA)

PS: With your given parameters everything matches